# Youtube Video Search List Pagination

Tags: youtube, pagination, youtube-api, search-engine

I want the youtube fetch videos have Next/Prev pagination button. 
Thanks

Comment: No one here, Plz help i still didn't get any help from internet. Thanks

Comment: No one going to help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you aren't sending the page token on to the actual API request ... you pass it from one of your pages to another, but then neglect to add it to your listSearch object. Try adding this as an item in the array passed as an argument to the listSearch:

```
'pageToken' => $_GET['ptk']
```

Comment: My Above Code isn't displaying these informations:
Duration,View Count,Likes,Dislikes.

The Youtube listSearch function isn't outputting these contentDetails for search results videos. Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: You should ask a new question rather than tag on more questions here ... that way it helps others who are searching for the same thing.